# Divide two measures from two different tables

Tags: powerbi

I have to divide two measures from two different tables. I have created a measure in Table A & created measure-2 in Table B.
When I use matrix visual in Power BI by taking date field in columns and region in rows (for table A&B), I can see the both table values are correct as I am expected.

Ex: Table A 2017-Q1 value by measure1 is 29.2, Table B 2017-Q1 value by measure1 is 2.9.

I have to divide both measures and I need to show the value (divide%) in TableA along with Measure1.
Unfortunately I tried in multiple ways by forming relationship b/w two tables also, But not getting the expected result i.e., 29.2/2.9 we should get 10% but instead of that getting 3%.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! Edit your question and add some dummy data, current relationship between tables + your measure definition

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data model, it's hard to give a reasonable answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax

Your best change of understanding what happens is to learn up on relations, and changes them when needed. The documentation is a great starting point.

Unrelated data plotted in a visual of different data will always aggregate since there is no relation to split your values. The value of 3% is correct, your assumption that you want 10% as an outcome is not valid for your situation.

If you link the dates of table A and the dates of table B to a seperate Calendar, it all would work.